# Ajax call on class returns old data

Tags: ajax, javascript

I'm facing this issue since days and I don't know what to do, my problem is the following.

For example, I have this class:

```
class My_Class
{
    public $attr;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dummy_function();
    }

    public function dummy_function()
    {
        $this->attr = 0;
        add_action('wp_ajax_click_trigger_one', array($this, 'modify_value'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_click_trigger_two', array($this, 'get_value'));
    }

    public function modify_value()
    {
        $this->attr = 1;
        return $this->attr;
    }

    public function get_value()
    {
        return $this->attr;
    }
}
```

But when I execute my code in the following order, I receive this:

```
new My_Class();
// Trigger click one -- returns 1
// trigger click two -- returns 0
```

I want my second click to return 1, why isn't my class preserving the values changed? How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Classes and functions don't preserve data after the script has finished. If you need to somehow connect the data of two separate ajax requests, you should store the data in the database using the [Transient API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. The problem is that instead one number (like in my example) I have one instance of an object in "this->attr", and of course, I cannot save that inside a Transient. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You're welcome. What are you trying to do? If you want to preserve a class's data after the script is terminated, there's probably something wrong with your approach, unless you want to cache data, which in that case you can use a server side cache, which isn't that easy to implement and not every server supports it.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a [Background processor](https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing) in my project, its instance is supposed to be contained in a wrapper class. I construct this wrapper, assign the bg processor to one property of this wrapper, and runs ok. But when I hit this wrapper class with my ajax to check status (like in the example), I receive an empty answer, like if the background processor wasn't used and is not executing (it is running in the background). It's weird because when I add data to the BProcessor, and later I run it with another ajax, everything works.